# How can I do ng-repeat with a firebase Array?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Context**

In a Firebase DB I'm storing "*events*" and "*users*". Users can have favorite events, to manage them I only store the event's id in the favorite user's DB location. So to grab favorite events informations, I need to firstable grab the event id and then go to the DB events location, to collect all the datas I need.

[image]

**Problem**

I would like to store in an Array all the favorite events informations (each event would be an Object with inside it : "key" : "value"), to use that Array in my HTML view and print the informations. But it doesn't work the way I coded it... :(

```js
   // This ref is too grab favorite event id (in my case only 2) in the user DB location
    var refUserFavoris = firebase.database().ref().child("users/"+user.uid+"/events/favoris"); 
    $scope.favorisTmp = $firebaseArray(refUserFavoris);

    // This shows one array, with two objects (wich are my two user's favorite events) wich include ids
    console.log($scope.favorisTmp);

    // This is to load the objects and with the foreEach, grab there ids to use them in the next ref call
    $scope.favorisTmp.$loaded().then(function() 
    {
            angular.forEach($scope.favorisTmp, function(favoris) 
            {
                // This shows two lines : the id of each object
                console.log(favoris.$id);

                // Call a new ref to reach the event informations (in a different location of the DB) using the previous id
                firebase.database().ref("events/"+favoris.$id).once('value').then(function(snapshot) 
                {
                    // Attempt to store events datas for each id I have (in my case, only two)
                    snapshot.forEach(function(favorisSnap) 
                    {
                        var favSnap = favorisSnap.val();

                        // This shows a lot of "undefined" lines, wich I don't want. I would like two objects, with all informations inside
                        console.log(favSnap.nbPersonne);

                        // $scope.favorisF is an Array that I would like to use in a ng-repeat to print all datas for each event
                        // For now this doesn't show anything
                        $scope.favorisF = favSnap;
                    });

                    // If using favSnap out of the previous function, I got a "favSnap" is undifined error
                    console.log(favSnap);
                });
            });
    });
```

```html
<ion-item ng-repeat="f in favorisF" class="item-avatar">
    {{f.nbPersonne}}
</ion-item>
```

**EDIT 1 :**

I tried a new way to have my data, but a new problem came, how to fill an Array inside a loop ? I've tried "push" and "$add" methods, but no one worked. Any ideas ?

```js
        var newFav = [];
        var user;
        user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        var refUserFavoris = firebase.database().ref().child("users/"+user.uid+"/events/favoris");
        
        $scope.favorisTmp = $firebaseArray(refUserFavoris);
        
        $scope.favorisTmp.$loaded().then(function()
        {
                angular.forEach($scope.favorisTmp, function(favoris) 
                {
                    console.log(favoris.$id);
                    var refFavoris = firebase.database().ref("events/"+favoris.$id);
                    refFavoris.on('value', function(snap)
                    {
                       //This is where I'm trying to fill "newFav" in each steps of the loop
                       newFav.push(snap.val());
                       console.log("Scope newFav vaut :", $scope.newFav);
                    });
                });
        });
```

Comment: Is somebody, has a clue to help me ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a typo here.

`var refUserFavoris  = firebase.database().ref("events/favoris/"+favoris.$id).once('value')`

Comment: I don't think so, the problem here is "favoris" variable become declared only at this loop line : angular.forEach($scope.favorisTmp, function(favoris).
I've tried an other method since this post, an a new problem comes, how to fill an array during a loop ? Tried the "push" and "$add" methods, but no one worked...

Comment: Are you sure `nbPersonne` is a key under each event?

Comment: @Memphis Please fix your snippets as they dont work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot Abdel, I fixed my problem :

**Here is the solution**

```js
$scope.newFav = [];
        console.log($scope.newFav);
        
        $scope.favorisTmp.$loaded().then(function()
        {
                angular.forEach($scope.favorisTmp, function(favoris) 
                {
                    console.log(favoris.$id);
                    var refFavoris = firebase.database().ref("events/"+favoris.$id);
                    refFavoris.on('value', function(snap)
                    {
                       $scope.newFav.push(snap.val());
                       console.log("Scope newFav vaut :", $scope.newFav);
                    });
                });
        });
```

Comment: Watch out because while your solution might work, whenever the data set changes, you will be pushing new items to the array which is maybe not what you want. I would advise you to use `once` instead.

Comment: Oh didn't see that point, where in my solution would you see that "once" ?

Comment: Its the method you call on the `firebase.database.Reference` which in your case is the `refFavoris` that you're using in combination with `on`. Check out the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#detach_listeners) for more explaination